# Providing Ninject with constructor dependencies it can't resolve?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

**Disclaimer**: I'm quite new to DI and IoC, please forgive any drastic misunderstandings.

Consider a `ClassB` that requires a object implementing `IClassA`. Ninject should be able to inject instances of `ClassA` into the constructor of `ClassB`, assuming it can construct instances of `ClassA`:

```
public class ClassA : IClassA
{
    public ClassA(string runtimeDependency) { /* ... */ }
}

public class ClassB : IClassB
{
    public ClassB(IClassA depA) { /* ... */ }
}

public sealed class TestBootstrapModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IClassA>().To<ClassA>();
        Bind<IClassB>().To<ClassB>();
    }
}
```

Now, let's say some runtime logic is involved in deriving the `string runtimeDependency` provided to `ClassA`. How should I provide Ninject with `runtimeDependency` so that it can provide `ClassB` with instances of `ClassA`?

The string will only be determined once, so I don't need to worry about injecting a new value into each instance.

Answer (score 2):

One *way* to do it is to provide the `ClassA` via a method.  Also keep in mind that with Ninject 2, you don't need modules and can do bindings directly in the Kernel.

```
Bind<IClassA>().ToMethod(_ => 
  {
     // do something interesting with a runtimeDependancy
     return new ClassA(someInterestingVariable);
  });
```

I'm really taking a stab as to *when* your runtime variable is available and it's scope.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned variable lifetime and scope; what if the variable yet doesn't exist at the time of binding? (I'm believing I should initialize all of my bindings early and in a common location.)

Comment: @robjb: That seems like it's more of a design problem, not a ninject one.  Without more context, it'll be hard to say.  You're only determining the string once, so it would most likely require to you either do *all* your bindings after that is set.  Keep in mind, I'm by no means a Ninject expert.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options here depending on your design, and specific problem. The first, easiest solution is to just provide the value when you request your service from Ninject

```
Kernel.Get<IClassA>("runtimeDependencyValue");
```

If this is not possible however, things get a bit more interesting. The way I've solved this previously is to actually create contextual bindings to `System.String` itself.

Say if I want to bind a connection string, I'll create a custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class ConnectionStringAttribute : Attribute     
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Denotes the setting that you want to populate the given property with.
    /// </summary>
    public string SettingName { get; private set; }

    public ConnectionStringAttribute(string configSettingName = "")
    {
        SettingName = configSettingName;
    }
}
```

and then I decorate my service constructor like this:

```
public class ClassA : IClassA
{
    public ClassA([ConnectionString("AppDB")] string runtimeDependency) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Finally, my binding will look something like this:

```
Bind<string>()
    .ToMethod(ctx => 
    {
        var attr = (ConnectionStringAttribute)context.Request.Target.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ConnectionStringAttribute), true).First();
        string settingName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(attr.SettingName) ? context.Request.Target.Name : attr.SettingName;
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[settingName].ConnectionString;
    })
    .WhenTargetHas<ConnectionStringAttribute>();
```

You get the idea. Hope this helps :)